Service returned error code AccessDeniedException (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403)
I tried deploying my code on my stage using a pipeline created in my code. It had been working fine for 1 year now. But today when I tried to deploy using the pipeline or tried to deploy it manually I got this error. Now I am not sure why this is happening. Some where people said it can be due to billing issue of my Aws account but that is not the case in some documents I read that this can be due to insufficient permissions to my IAM role but that is also not the case.
Error:
UPDATE_FAILED: CustomDashresourceDashapigwDashcwDashroleLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "Service returned error code AccessDeniedException (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: )" (RequestToken:, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied) 

Can anyone who has been through this and has resolved this issue help me out? Thanks in advance

Could you share your github action workflow configuration in the question please, so that we can have a minimal example to reproduce the reported scenario?

I have found the solution basically I had made a big mistake, I created a repo on github which was public and pushed my revamped code over there then I made it private. I forgot that I used the twilio auth key as a direct value instead of using it as an env due to which when I pushed my code on the repo the key got publicly exposed and when I pushed my previous code which was live it was using the same key in the env due to which Aws was restricting my deployment.
